# "bad value for restricted picklist field" + field value error

Tags: salesforce

When the user is trying to send an email from an email action, the "bad value for restricted picklist field" + field value error is triggering.

I verified, Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set checkbox is checked on the error thrown picklist field. When we uncheck the checkbox, the issue is resolved. I would like to know do we have any other alternatives for this issue without unchecking the checkbox "Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set".

Comment: Well, make sure the email action (or trigger, or flow...) selects something from valid picklist values? Write a "before insert" trigger that detects bad values and overwrites them or sets to null? Not sure what answer you expect?